# How to do silent login to online.microsoft.com using hello.js

Tags: authentication, silent, hello.js

i want to do auto silent login to https://nam.delve.office.com/?p=emailId&v=work
from my application so that i can get user profile image from microsoft
but above URL redirecting to online.microsoft.com for user authentication .

can anyone help me how can i do this silent login using hello.js from my application

Thanks,